# Firebase code lab: Friendly Chat server hosting CANNOT GET /

Tags: firebase

https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#0
Step 5. Running the command `firebase serve --only hosting` starts the hosting at 'http://localhost:5000' and displays 'Cannot GET /' instead of the Friendly Chat template within the code lab.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue. In firebase.json, the public path needs to be "./public/index.html"

It should look like:

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./public/index.html",
    "headers": [{
      "source" : "**/*.@(js|html)",
      "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Cache-Control",
        "value" : "max-age=0"
      } ]
    }]
  }
}
```